# How to detect what sort of token user is using

Tags: oauth-2.0

Im building API on my project with oauth server for authorization(i ve took https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php).
Users will be able to write their own applications and integrate their into my project by iframe.

I have two sorts of permission for API users:

1. API methods which may be called by appllication directly (grant type=client_credentials)
2. When an application calls API methods on behalf of current user when user authorize access to his data for the application  (grant type=authorization_code)

So there will two types of access tokens on my project and how can i detect what type of token user using in this time and allow or restrict his actions?

p/s/ Sorr for poor english and possible mistakes in the text.

Answer (score 1):

> So there will two types of access tokens on my project and how can i
>   detect what type of token user using in this time and allow or
>   restrict his actions?

The format of the access tokens is not part of the OAuth specification. You could choose for example the [`JWT`](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html) access token format. So in the case of an access token issued on behalf of the user you could have the username or the email as claim in the access token. So when validating it at the resource server (your API) you could look for the presence of this claim in the access token payload.